# Replace empty values in nested json

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains nested columns as below when converted in to json format.

```json
{"id" : 1,
 "address":
  {"adress1":"",
   "city" : "TX",
   "zip": ""
  },
 "gender": "",
  "code": 999
}
```

The dataframe is normalized and will be written in to snowflake variant column. I would like to replace empty values("") with nulls before it inserted in to snowflake.

I tried using `df.replace('',np.NAN, inPlace='True)`. But it replaced only gender with null. I am not able to see address1 and zip value with nulls. They are still empty. Can someone help how we can handle this scenario.

Comment: Why not try replacing the nested values (`''`  -> `np.Nan` ) inside the python `dict` first and then pass it to the dataframe?

Comment: Fetching source data from an API. API response is in json format. We are normalizing the response using pandas as df = pd.json_normalize(response)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```py
str_response = json.dumps(response)
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(str_response))
df.replace('',np.NAN, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

---

```
   id  gender  code  address.address1 address.city  address.zip
0   1     NaN   999               NaN           TX          NaN
```